# MYSQL Data Base Location Windows 10 PC

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

mysql workbench 6.3

I am trying to find the location of My Data Base so I can copy it to another
storage device as a backup of my data but I can not seem to find it

Can you help me locate it

Is there an *.ini file that will tell me

No MYSQL folder under 'Program Data"

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default location is right in the root directory being C:\mysql

Comment: It seems it was installed in in C:\wamp64

Comment: Ah you installed WAMP and not just MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Search the system for my.ini which should exist somewhere!
There should be a datadir line in there with the info you need, in my case:

datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Data

Comment: It seems to have been in stalled in C;\wamp64 any one know the significance of the directory wamp64 is it because I am using workbench?

Comment: WAMP = Windows Apache MySQL PHP, i.e. a bundle allowing you to deploy web applications using (apart from the Windows element) open source software.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to use the [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) utility to create a backup of the database in a single file.

Manipulating the underlying files directly is an advanced operation.

Copying the files with the server running will not result in a valid backup.  Restoring using the files will not work, to varying degrees, if you miss anything.